Google Maps navigation is dropping during screen off
My Google Navigator now dropping navigation if I turn my screen off. Before that I was able to navigate by audio hints from my pocket, now I am unable to do this. Once I turn my screen off, navigation stops.
Moreover, when I turn my screen back on, navigation doesn't continue automatically. First it tries to trace a route again and requires me to press "Start" button.
Power saving options are OFF, Maps application has Location, Notifications and Physical activivty permissions granted.
How to fix?

What phone model by which manufacturer and running what Android version do you use?
